# How to show div top concerning stacking context

Tags: javascript, css, z-index, css-transforms, display

What i want to achieve is simple. When card is flipped, the "conTent" div (with black color) could be top on of all other "cardFront" div (with red color). 
I know that you can't use zindex here, because they have different stacking context, so i think i should fouce on div "cardBack" and "cardFront", because they both have transform attribute which makes them become stacking context element. But it's a bit complex that it's about "cardBack" and "cardFront" that belong to different higher stacking context element "flipper".
So i'm confused that what really depends the show sequence, is the level of stacking context?Can i manually set the level? Right now it's seems that DOM sequence determines. Like the middle card, when it is flipped, the "content" is on top of previous "cardFront", but below the next "cardFront".
i used a method that set different display mode, some blog said that inline-block has a higher level than block, but it seems doesn't work.So i really need some help here, thanks!

```js
const root = document.querySelector("#root");


class Card extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {

    return ( 
      <div className = "flipperContainer" >
        <div className = "flipper" >
          <div className = "cardFront" >
          </div> 
          <div className = "cardBack" >
            <div className = "conTent" >
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
class CardContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (  
      <div className = "flex" >
        <Card / >

        <Card / >

        <Card / >
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( < CardContainer / > , root);
```

```css
.flipperContainer{
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  width: 70px;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.flipperContainer:hover .flipper,
.flipperContainer.hover .flipper {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flipper {
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  -o-transition: 1s;
  transition: 1s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  border-radius: 35px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  
}


/* hide back of pane during swap */

.cardFront,
.cardBack {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}


/* front pane, placed above back */

.cardFront {
  display:block
  width: 70px;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 99;
  background-color: red;
  /* for firefox 31 */
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}


/* back, initially hidden pane */

.cardBack {
  display:inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.conTent {
  display:inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}
.flex {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```